# Django no sessionid in cookie

Tags: python, django, rest, django-1.6

Im using Mongo Engine/REST Framework with Django 1.6.

All I need is for the client to get a sessionid when he hits one of the views. However at the moment no sessionid is present in the cookie.

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def updateInput(request):
    return HttpResponse("view has been hit")
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = Common.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES + ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',)
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django.contrib.sessions',)

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'

DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.sessions',
)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#technical-details), a user has no session until it is necessary:

> Django only sends a cookie if it needs to. If you don’t set any session data, it won’t send a session cookie.

You need to set some session data, then you will find the `sessionid` in the cookie.

Comment: This worked on the view. But on my other view the key returns null even though i perform the session key update and lookup for the session id before any serialization is performed (??)

Comment: Still having issues but updated question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713650/django-rest-mongodb

Comment: The Django docs Link doesn't work: [working Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/#technical-details)

Comment: Thanks @Pankov, I've fixed the link :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this answer won't help you, but will definitely help those like I came across your question. If you are using the cookie from javascript, for example as part of an ajax request, you will need to set the following in your settings.py

```
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=False
```